# Magento: Speeding Up Layered Navigation

Tags: magento

A common way to speed up Magento is to disable layered navigation, however, some shops need it for big catalogs.

Rather than disable it, I would like to keep it and make it work as quickly as a normal category.

How can this be achieved?
Flat catalogs don't really make it that much faster.
Full page cache is pointless as there are two many combinations of filters and most views would be a non-cached result.
SOLR might be a option, but i'm unsure how this would be installed in Magento.

Comment: You're asking a broad question on Magento optimization, which is covered in several topics and articles already available.

Comment: This is not a programming related question. You should ask this on https://magento.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate solr by developing your own extension and using a client library such as solr-pecl or solarium.
So you should first index your data in solr.
and then intercept the creation of the layer view and filter blocks and get data from solr after sending request with faceted fields specified in the query and then just get the response and inject it into the blocks of the filters.